# django model translation - filter by translated field

Tags: python, django, django-modeltranslation

I need to query like:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(title_de="some title")
```

where `de` inside `title_de` is dynamic

I cannot do:

```
MyModel.objects.filter('title_%s' % language = "some title")
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use kwargs,

```
kwargs = {
    f"title_{language}": "some title"
}
MyModel.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

If, in your example, `language` is the current language, then this will work out of the box. See the [modeltranslation docs](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#multilingual-manager):

> It works as follow: if the translation field name is used (`title`), it is changed into the current language field name (`title_de` or `title_en`, depending on the current active language). Any language-suffixed names are left untouched (so `title_en` wouldn’t change, no matter what the current language is).

There is no fallback in case there is no translation available for the given language (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418377/django-modeltranslation-queries-fallback)), so this has the same effect as specifically querying a language-specific field.